# Python Yfinance - Can't get SPY history

Tags: python, yfinance

I'm following a tutorial on using Yfinance in Jupyter Notebook to get prices for SPY (S&P 500) in a dataframe. The code looks simple, but I can't seem to get the desired results.

```
df_tickers = pd.DataFrame() 
spyticker = yf.Ticker("SPY")
print(spyticker)
df_ticker = spyticker.history(period="max", interval="1d", start="1998-12-01", end="2022-01-01" , auto_adjust=True, rounding=True)
df_ticker.head()
```

The error states: "SPY: No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted." But when I print spyticker, I get the correct yfinance object:

```
yfinance.Ticker object <SPY>
```

Comment: At this time, the data can be retrieved correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your problem is but if I use the following:

```
spyticker = yf.Ticker("SPY")
df_ticker = spyticker.history(period="max", interval="1d", start="1998-12-01", end="2022-01-01" , auto_adjust=True, rounding=True)
df_ticker.head()
```

I get the following:

```
    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Dividends   Stock Splits
Date                            
1998-12-01  76.02   77.27   75.43   77.00   8950600 0.0 0
1998-12-02  76.74   77.19   75.94   76.78   7495500 0.0 0
1998-12-03  76.76   77.45   75.35   75.51   12145300    0.0 0
1998-12-04  76.35   77.58   76.27   77.49   10339500    0.0 0
1998-12-07  77.29   78.21   77.25   77.86   4290000 0.0 0
```

My only explanation is that the call to `spyticker.history` already returns a dataframe, so it isn't necessary to define the df_ticker beforehand.  ​

Comment: Thank you! It might be a Jupyter notebook issue in that case, I will have to try with other environments

Comment: I made the call using Jupyter Notebook without any issue.